# Access instance variable inside a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

How can I in the easiest way access an instance variable inside a function?

```
function MyObject(){

     //Instance variables
     this.handler;

     //Methods
     this.enableHandler = function(){
         var button = document.getElementById('button');
         button.onclick = function(){
             this.handler();//Is not working
         }
     }

}
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.handler = function(){
    alert('Hello World!');
}
myObject.enableHandler();
```

Note that I can set `button.onclick = this.handler;`. This is just an example. The main question is how I can access `this.handler` inside that function?

I can also define a new variable `var handler = this.handler`to access `this.handler`. But If a change `handler`will `this.handler` also be changes?

Comment: You mentioned jQuery but I don't see you using it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function MyObject(){

     //Instance variables
     this.handler;
     var that = this;  //notice change
     //Methods
     this.enableHandler = function(){
         var button = document.getElementById('button');
         button.onclick = function(){
             that.handler();//Is not working  notice the change
         }
     }

}
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.handler = function(){
    alert('Hello World!');
}
myObject.enableHandler();
```

If you assign this to a var within the scope of the outer function, it is passed to the inner functions scope chain. Within your inner function referencing this refers to the inner function, referencing the variable you assigned this, in our case "that", refers back to that object.

Comment: Ok if I change `that.handler` will `this.handler` also be changed?

Comment: yes but you also need to do the var that = this; assignment, look at the two places i put notice change in the comments.