# Access an instance variable inside an anonymous function inside prototype method

Tags: javascript, oop

This is actually a follow up question to my previous question, [Access instance variable inside a function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538401/access-instance-variable-inside-a-function-in-javascript).

I want to access an instance variable inside an anonymous function inside prototype method.

```
function MyObject(){

     //Instance variables
     this.handler;

}
//Methods
MyObject.prototype.enableHandler = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.onclick = function(){
         this.handler();//Is not working
    }
}
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.handler = function(){
    alert('Hello World!');
}
myObject.enableHandler();
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3cmvZ/

The example above was just to clarify how I can access an instance variable inside an anonymous function inside a prototype method. I already know that `button.onclick = this.handler` works.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that the anonymous function is in the prototype, but rather that it is an event handler (which is not invoked as a method).

The problem is that in your onclick handler, the `this` keywords is bound to the `windows` object, not to the `myObject` instance that the prototype is set on. You can store the object in a `that` variable and create a closure:

```
function MyObject(){

     //Instance variables
     this.handler;

}
//Methods
MyObject.prototype.enableHandler = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    var that = this;
    button.onclick = function(){
         that.handler();//Should be working
    }
}
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.handler = function(){
    alert('Hello World!');
}
myObject.enableHandler();
```

Comment: If I change `that.handler`will this.handler also be changed?

Comment: as long as `that` and `this` are the same object then yes.

Answer (score 2):

`this.handler` is not in the same scope. You need to declare it as:

```
MyObject.prototype.enableHandler = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = this.handler;
}
```

As you are simply calling the event directly, you need not wrap it in another function.

**Update** based on your comment:

```
MyObject.prototype.enableHandler = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var $this = this;

    button.onclick = function() {
        $this.handler();
    }
}
```

You need to make a local variable that is in the same scope as the anonymous function.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the example was just to clarify how I can access an instance variable inside an anonymous function inside a prototype method. I already know that `button.onclick = this.handler` works

Comment: If I change `$this.handler` will this.handler also be changed?'